# Elasticsearch always returning "mapping type is missing"

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm following the advice given here in order to find partial words with elasticsearch:

[ElasticSearch n-gram tokenfilter not finding partial words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044674/elasticsearch-n-gram-tokenfilter-not-finding-partial-words)

I've created a simple bash script that attempts to run a version of this:

```
curl -XDELETE 10.160.86.134:9200/products
curl -XPOST 10.160.86.134:9200/products -d '{
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
       "filter": {
         "mynGram" : {"type": "nGram", "min_gram": 2, "max_gram": 10}
       },
       "analyzer": {
         "a1" : {
           "type":"custom",
           "tokenizer": "standard",
           "filter": ["lowercase", "mynGram"]
         }
       }
     }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT 10.160.86.134:9200/products/_mapping -d '{
  "product" : {
    "index_analyzer" : "a1",
    "search_analyzer" : "standard",
    "properties" : {
      "product_description": {"type":"string"},
      "product_name": {"type":"string"}
    }
  }
}'
```

Following running this script the first two commands (dumping products, then setting the index) seem to work giving me this:

```
{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
```

Then it errors out following the mapping call giving me this:

```
{"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;]","status":500}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Searching google starts autocompleting "mapping not found elasticsearch" so it seems to be a very common error.

Comment: elasticsearch is still a young project, documentation is growing, but still lacking.  I usually get great responses on the mailing list, https://groups.google.com/group/elasticsearch

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Turns out this is happening because the mapping needs to be applied to the type:

I tried applying it to the wrong thing:

```
curl -XPUT 10.160.86.134:9200/products/_mapping -d '{
```

It needs to be applied to the type like so:

```
curl -XPUT 10.160.86.134:9200/products/product/_mapping -d '{
```

It's sad that a simple google search couldn't answer this.  Also the previous post I linked to is very misleading and the answer is wrong, which I'll point out there as well.

Comment: I'm with you. There just doesn't seem to be enough out there for elastic-search. The docs are not quite helpful enough, and searching doesn't help a lot. I had an error with _routing and couldn't find any answers anywhere. I also haven't tried out the IRC, but it probably could help.

Comment: Link to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) for reference.

Comment: Yes, put mapping endpoint is missing "mapping type" (such as `_doc`, or `product` in above example)

Answer (score 4):

Set mapping for the index is possible in Elastic search. I tried this with the latest version of Elastic search 1.7.3 and I was able to set the mapping successfully to the index.

I tried the following,

- Delete the index (DELETE http://localhost:9200/index)
- Put the mapping json under the index (PUT http://localhost:9200/index)
- Get the mapping (GET http://localhost:9200//_mapping)

Answer (score -1):

I think Travis was right, maybe this error came from some old version of ES, a "type" in some old version of ES is just like a table in the relational database, an "index" is like a database, a "doc" is like a record. Nowadays, the "type" seemed to disappear.

you can see this from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html).
[image]

I don't know why I can't upload a picture.