# problems with elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

As the guide stated, 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html#_mapping_options

I could use an array of lat/lon variables, and map it to geo_point type.

so here is my current mapping:

```
{
   "zoek": {
      "mappings": {
         "geo": {
            "properties": {
               "country": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "geonameid": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "locatie": {
                  "type": "double"
               },
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

"locatie" refers to an array of two double. [ lat, lon ].

I want to map this to the geo_point variable to perform geo distance queries.

so i tried this:

```
PUT /zoek/geo/_mapping 
{
    "geo" : {
        "properties" : {
            "locatie" : {"type" : "geo_point" }
        }
    }
}
```

and got this error:

```
{
   "error": "MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [locatie] of different type, current_type [double], merged_type [geo_point]]}]",
```

"status": 400
    }

Any suggestions?

Greets,

Dagmar.

Answer (score 2):

In a given mapping type (i.e. `geo`), you cannot define two fields with the same name (i.e. `locatie`) but a different type (i.e. one as `double` and another as `geo_point`). Since you already have a field name `locatie` in your `geo` mapping type, you cannot add a new one with the same name, but you can definitely add another with a different name, e.g. `location_geo`.

However, I suggest changing your original mapping and replace your `locatie` (as `double`) with `locatie` (as `geo_point`). If you do so, you'll need to reindex your existing data, though, so that might not be an option for you.

Comment: curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/zoek/geo/0 -d ' { "geonameid" : "2743463", "name" : "Den Oord", "locatie" : [ 51.9708300,   5.2708300], "country" : "NL"  } ';

Comment: How do you change the original mapping? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8160896/1736679) and got a similar error `mapper [source.geoip.coordinates] of different type, current_type [double], merged_type [geo_point]`