# Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing; in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm was an error same [this questuion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160234/elasticsearch-always-returning-mapping-type-is-missing).
As the answer of this question i'm trying to set correct url to PUT index mapping, but it's not work on my instance:

```
$ cat mapping.json | http PUT myhost:9200/acastest/_mapping
```

result:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 247
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
    "error": {
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;", 
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;", 
                "type": "action_request_validation_exception"
            }
        ], 
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception"
    }, 
    "status": 400
}
```

and trying with this:

```
$ cat mapping.json | http PUT myhost:9200/acastest/articles/_mapping
```

result:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 3969
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
    "error": {
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {articles={properties={category_en={type=string, index=not_analyzed},blah blah blah", 
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {articles={properties={category_en={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, category_fa={blahblah blah", 
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception"
            }
        ], 
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception"
    }, 
    "status": 400
}
```

Elasticsearch config:

```
"version": {

    "number": "2.1.1",
    "build_hash": "40e2c53a6b6c2972b3d13846e450e66f4375bd71",
    "build_timestamp": "2015-12-15T13:05:55Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "5.3.1"

},
```

and my mapping file like this:

```
{ 
    "mappings": {
            "articles": {
                "properties": {
                    "category_en": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "category_fa": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    blah
                    blah
                    blah
                }
            }
        }
}
```

To see complete mapping file, check [this](https://gist.github.com/kharazi/2a97b39a8cb05b211fba)
How can i fix it?

Comment: You need to remove `"mappings"`and have `"articles"` at the top level in your `mapping.json` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two solutions:

A. If you want to run

```
$ cat mapping.json | http PUT myhost:9200/acastest/articles/_mapping
```

You need to change your `mapping.json` file like this:

```
    { 
        "articles": {
            "properties": {
                "category_en": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "category_fa": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                blah
                blah
                blah
            }
        }
    }
```

B. Or you can keep your `mapping.json` file like it is now, but then you need to run the following command instead:

```
$ cat mapping.json | http PUT myhost:9200/acastest
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

change URL to:

```
http://myhost:9200/acastest/_mapping/articles
```

Changing `mapping.json` to:

```
{
    "articles": {
        "properties": {
            "category_en": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "category_fa": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            blah
            blah
            blah
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
curl -X PUT "http://myhost:9200/acastest/mappings
```