# How to update dynamic_templates on all existing indices?

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm using ElasticSearch 5.1 and [elasticsearch.js 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-5-0.html). We have many different applications in production, which may have our platform default indices or custom ones. And we don't know their names. For new indices, I was able to add the following [`dynamic_template`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/dynamic-templates.html) using [`indices.putTemplate()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-5-0.html#api-indices-puttemplate-5-0):

```js
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({ /*...*/ });
var params = { 
  //...
  "body" : {
    "template":"*",
    "settings":{           
      "index.mapper.dynamic":true
      //...           
    },
    "mappings":{
      "_default_":{
        "properties":{
          //...
        },
        "dynamic_templates":[{
          "template_purchases_inner_fields": {
            "path_match":"purchases.*",
            "mapping": { "include_in_all": false }
          }
        }
        //, ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};
client.indices.putTemplate(params,function(err,resp){})
```

However, the [Index templates docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/indices-templates.html) say

> Templates are only applied at index creation time. Changing a template will have no impact on existing indices

The [Dynamic templates docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/dynamic-templates.html) say

> New templates can be appended to the end of the list with the PUT mapping API

The [PUT mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/indices-put-mapping.html)  has some examples, none of which fit to my scenario. An answer using [`indices.putMapping()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-5-0.html#api-indices-putmapping-5-0) would be extra helpful, but not necessary. Thanks for your time!

---

[*Edited on 8-21-2017*, Solar Eclipse day] 
This is the code I tried to change it through the JS API:

```js
var dynamicTemplates = [{
    "template_purchases_inner_fields": {
      "path_match": "purchases.*",
      "mapping": { "include_in_all": false}
    }
  }
  //...
  ];

params = { body:  {   "dynamic_templates": dynamicTemplates   }};
params.index = "_all";
params.type = "_default_";
//...
client.indices.putMapping(params,function(err,resp){})
```

And this is the code through Linux curl, w/ the `properties` field removed. **Please notice that you should re-add here other templates** not to override the previous ones:

```bash
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_all/_default_/_mapping -d "{\"_default_\":{\"dynamic_templates\":[{\"template_purchases_inner_fields\":{\"mapping\":{\"include_in_all\":false},\"path_match\":\"purchases.*\"}}]}}"
```

Checking on [elasticsearch-head](https://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/), on both cases, the mapping was updated on existing indices too, as if it worked. However, the `include_in_all=false` behavior was not achieved, meaning we could still see results on searching `_all` on records containing the inner objects under `purchases.*` on existing indices.

---

Related items:

- [Create or update mapping in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471715/create-or-update-mapping-in-elasticsearch)
- [ElasticSearch client.indices.putMapping always fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708006/elasticsearch-client-indices-putmapping-always-fail)
- [PutMapping api url is incorrect](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/102)

Comment: Using the Put Mapping API (through curl HTTP and through the JS client ), I was able to update the mapping to existing indices; however, the `include_in_all=false` behavior was not achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current answer is we **cannot** apply it to an existing index, based on the [Index templates docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/indices-templates.html):

> Templates are only applied at index creation time. Changing a template will have no impact on existing indices